# PHP different behavior between localhost and server

Tags: php

```
function feedSearch($url) {

      if($html = @DOMDocument::loadHTML(file_get_contents($url))) {

          $xpath = new DOMXPath($html);

          $feeds = $xpath->query("//head/link[@href][@type='application/rss+xml']/@href");

          if($feeds->length != 0){
            $url = rtrim($url, '/');

            if(strpos($url, 'https://')){
              $url = ltrim($url, 'https://');
              return $feedURL = $url . "/feed";
            }else{
              return $feedURL = $url . "/feed";
            }

          } 
  }

  return false;

}
if(feedSearch($url)){
  $xml = feedSearch($url);
}else{
    echo $url . " is not a valid feed URL.";
    die();
}
```

Above code work well in my localhost but not in my server. In server it will die. I've no idea what's missing in my server. How to debug version problem in PHP?

Comment: Check your server error log

Comment: @madforstrength on my server?

Comment: Also you might need to `allow_url_fopen` in your server php.ini file

Answer (score 1):

You need to add `allow_url_fopen = On` in your server's php.ini file.

Or if you do not have access to php.ini file than you can add `php_value allow_url_fopen On` in your .htaccess file.

Or as pointed out by @Ohgodwhy its better to use curl. 
You can make your own function using curl and then use it instead of `file_get_contents`:

```
function get_contents_from_url($url)
{
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

    $response = curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    return $response;
}
```

Comment: You should probably consider using something safe, such as cURL. As anyone could modify that endpoint and input malicious data into your stream.

Comment: Agreed with @Ohgodwhy

Comment: I switched to curl, I still need allow_url_fopen = On?

Comment: No for curl you dont need `allow_url_fopen = On` but you will need curl extension to be enabled on server, which most of the hostings already have.

Comment: If you want to check what components and extensions are available on your hosting than you can simply execute this line on a separate php page: `phpinfo();`

Comment: @madforstrength my local host work but not my server, that's strange.. in my server I have both curl and allow_url_fopen On, take a look : http://daysof.me/57/wp_scrapper/phpinfo.php

Comment: Your `allow_url_include` is off you need to turn it on as well

Comment: @madforstrength allow_url_include is off in my localhost, that's not the problem.

Comment: Than you need to try curl, it will work without doing anything on server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/68031/discussion-between-jamie-eason-and-madforstrength).